# Find min value of member, MDX

Tags: max, ssas, mdx, min

Just started to explore MDX. Can anyone help me to get below result.

Looking to build a MDX query which gives same out as below SQL query

select max(date),min(date) from Fiscal_calendar

Where :
1. Fiscal_Calendar is dimension in cube
2. date is the attribute

Answer (score 3):

Min Date will be the First Child of the [All] member while Max Date will be the Last Child.

```
SELECT {Fiscal_Calendar.Date.[All].FirstChild, Fiscal_Calendar.Date.[All].LastChild} ON 1,
{} ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
```

Second last child:

```
Fiscal_Calendar.Date.[All].LastChild.Lag(1)
```

Comment: Thanks SouravA! now I'm able to see firstchild value but I'm getting blank for lastchild. Can you guide me to fetch lastchild value which is not blank?

Comment: Is your LastChild always blank? How is the second last child? If it's certain to be not blank, can you fetch the second last child always?

Comment: Yes. Last child was blank. Your snippet worked out for me.. Bunch of thanks!

Comment: @reachyathish what does Sourav's second snippet return?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT {
        [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Quarter].members.item([Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Quarter].members.count-2)
        ,[Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Quarter].[All].firstChild
    } ON 1,{} ON 0 FROM [MyCube]
```

> Thanks @SourabA. Above code worked out to me. Do let me know if any better approach

Comment: Your answer is not consistent with the information you supplied. Also, you are basically doing the same thing as the answer I provided, in a slightly more complicated way.

Comment: Might be.. @sourabA could you suggest a better code item to get secondlastchild.. I could not find a MDX keyword

Comment: There is no better approach unless you are open to making changes to the cube structure. I added something for the second last child in my answer which at best is an alternative.

Comment: @reachyathish - you have reinvented Lag in your code! - stick to Sourav's suggestion. Why is the last member empty? This suggests a problem in your database.