# How calculate First Date in calculated Member?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, calculated-columns, cube

I need to have first filtered date in mdx that doesn't filter by date dimension that used in report rows.

I need that keep date filter but by pass dates that came in rows.

[image: Please check Sample Image]

Answer (score 1):

using MDX query you can use `FirstChild` property to get the first value of dimention members, assuming that the date dimension is called `DimDate` and the Date member is `Date`:

```
SELECT {DimDate.Date.[All].FirstChild} ON 1,
{ ... } ON 0
FROM [myCudbe]
```

Also you can use [MIN()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/min-mdx?view=sql-server-2017) function to retrieve the minimum date value, the link above *(official documentation)* contains a good example.

**Helpful links**

- [Find min value of member, MDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690554/find-min-value-of-member-mdx)
- [SSAS Calculated Member Aggregation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951555/ssas-calculated-member-aggregation-issue)
- [how to get min or max date on columns in mdx query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353306/how-to-get-min-or-max-date-on-columns-in-mdx-query)
- [How to get Minimum date in MDX Query](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/28030642-d9c3-4ceb-9977-4abe3db8bc15/how-to-get-minimum-date-in-mdx-query?forum=sqlanalysisservices)
- [Find first order date in MDX](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2012/09/find-first-order-date-in-mdx/)